# Dummy Load to test a 200 watt 24 volt supply

Tags: power-supply, resistors, dummy-load

I feel like I have a simple question that hopefully can be answered quite quickly. I have a 24V power supply that is supposed to achieve a max output of 200W. Recently, I have reason to believe that the supply has gone bad, and rather than damage anything down-line from this supply, I want to test the output with a dummy load.

Currently, I have just been making a dummy load by wiring a bunch of resistors in parallel, which gives me one net resistance of 13ohm (~45W of power). Ideally, I would like to make a dummy load that will cause the supply to consistently output ~80W of power. I feel like the bundle of resistors is really cumbersome, and that there is an easier way to do this, I am just unsure because I am a novice.

If anyone knows an easier way to make a dummy load that can undergo up to 200W, and is less cumbersome that would help me out a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Heating elements from clothes iron, owen, underfloor heating, or buy some resistive wire.

Comment: Several different power resistors that you can combine in series and parallel as needed. If you get 500 or 750 W resistors, they will not get TOO excessively hot when you test the supply. An example is the TE connectivity TE series of resistors: https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=9-1773453-2&DocType=DS&DocLang=English

Comment: Maybe heater from old car do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

12 volt halogen light bulbs are cheap and have cheap fittings.  Two 50 W bulbs in series gets you to 24 volts there's a load of 100 W.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have two 55W bulbs readily available!

Comment: this probably will trip the supplies short circuit protection,  check the resistance of the lamps when cold.

Comment: Except they are 10 times this power when cold and may trip the OCP

Comment: Can you understand why this will fail when the bulb with the higher resistance heats up, with PTC then drops more of the voltage and now you have >> 12V across one bulb and it burns out

Comment: Notice I simulated two 24V 50 W halogen bulbs with 10% tolerance . Due to PTC effects the 100W load starts at 1kW if it can handle  https://tinyurl.com/ybkaomsy  Press reset and use mouse to read values, on traces

Comment: I used this to test a 24V motor drive board I designed.  A couple of incandescent car headlights worked just dandy as a load.  **But** the thing was controlled to a current and voltage both, so when the commanded voltage wasn't yet reached, it'd go into current limit.  A typical supply may well trip, unless you use lots of little bulbs and switch them in one by one.

Comment: Or two by two, if they're 12V bulbs.

Comment: The two 55W bulbs I have are car headlight lamps. I was able to use this as a test without tripping the short on the supply. The supply does not have separate controls for current and voltage. From my understanding, it outputs a constant 24V and will adjust the current automatically.

Comment: @Dayman so you must be glad your supply is working. If you need to measure ripple, use an AC coupled 50 Ohm load

Answer (score 1):

For testing high power low voltage supplies I use a cheap inverter connected to the appropriate number of mains voltage quartz light bulbs. This forms a compact dummy load you just need to be careful about how you mount the bulb holders. I have them screwed to a piece of plywood.

Answer (score 0):

4 ohms will get you about 144 watts dissipation, so use that much steel wire strung between nails on a board as a resistor.

Comment: Better recheck that value. It’s too low